# Wait for function to finish running before iterating

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

How can I wait for the image.onload function to finish running before iterating the next value in an array??

```
for (let i = 0; i < Object.keys(images_list_complex_form).length; i++) {
    for (let k = 0; k < images_list_complex_form[i].length; k++) {
        console.log('ITERATE');
        image.onload = function () {
            console.log('STARTED IMAGE ON LOAD');
        }
    }
}
```

I am receiving multiple 'iterates' before receiving started image on load

As sugguested by @amadan, i have tried adding in async and await into the for loop however, after doing so the image111.onload is never triggered anymore. I never get to see the console log "Started image on load"

```
        async function rectifyMissingSavedImages(images_list_complex_form_array,annotationIndexArray){
            console.log(images_list_complex_form_array);
            for(let i = 0; i < Object.keys(images_list_complex_form_array).length; i++){
                for(const[index2,value2] of Object.entries(images_list_complex_form_array[i])){
                    if (Object.keys(annotationIndexArray).length == 0 || (!annotationIndexArray[i] || annotationIndexArray[i].includes(String(k)) == false)) {
                        let image_url = URL.createObjectURL(value2);
                        let image111 = new Image();
                        let canvas = new fabric.Canvas();
                        
                        console.log(image111);
                        await new Promise((resolve,reject) =>{
                            image111.onload = evt => {
                                console.log("??");
                                console.log('STARTED IMAGE ON LOAD');
                                let background = new fabric.Image(image);
                                canvas.setHeight(background.height);
                                canvas.setWidth(background.width);
                                canvas.setBackgroundImage(background, canvas.renderAll.bind(canvas));
                                console.log("ABOUT TO RESOLVE");

                                image.src = image_url;
                                resolve();
                            }
                        });
```

Comment: Can you use `await`/`async` in your project?

Comment: yes but i am not sure how to implement it

Comment: `image.onload` will trigger once the image is loaded; but loading starts when `image.src` is changed, and you change `image.src` inside `image.onload`... Move `image.src = image_url` two lines down. EDIT: Also, what is `image` anyway? You only have `image111`... EDIT2: Also, set `image111.onerror = reject`, as shown by t.niese.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The easiest way is to create and await a promise inside the loop. Something like:

```
async function loadImages() {
  for (...) {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      image.onload = evt => {
        console.log('STARTED IMAGE ON LOAD');
        resolve();
      }
      image.onerror = reject;
    });
  }
}
```

This is the only way that a loop can "pause" in JavaScript. Any other way involves either chaining promises, which is messy, or nesting callbacks, which is even worse.

Comment: i tried creating the for loop into a function but it resulted in the onload event to never get triggered, what have I done wrongly? I have edited my initial question with additional code that i have tried as based on your suggestion

Answer (score 2):

That task is not completely trivial. At least if `src` is already set
(the load of the image will start as soon as you set `src`).

So if the `src` is already set you need to determine two cases:

1. image already loaded
2. is still loading

This can be check with with [HTMLImageElement.complete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete)

Furthermore, you need to check for both the `load` or `error` case otherwise your loop might get stuck in case of a network error or when something else goes wrong with loading the image.

```js
// create a function to which you can pass the image
// that function will determine if the image was already loaded
// or it has to wait for the image to be loaded
function waitForImage(image) {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    // first check if image was already loaded
    if (image.src && image.complete) {
      // check if loading was successful
      // there might be better ways then checking its dimension
      // because this will fail if you load an image that has no size (like tracking pixels)
      if (image.width > 0 || image.height > 0) {
        resolve()
      } else {
        reject()
      }
    } else {
      // resolve in case a successful load
      image.onload = resolve
      // reject in case of an error
      image.onerror = reject
    }
  })
}

async function loadImages() {
  // create some dummy data to make the snipped runable
  let urls = [
    'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150',
    'https://via.placeeeeeeeholder.com/350x150', // intentional typo to make it fail
    'https://via.placeholder.com/350x150'
  ]

  let images = urls.map(url => {
    let image = new Image()
    image.src = url
    return image
  })

  // iterat over the images
  for (let image of images) {
    try {
      // call a function that returns a Promise 
      // and use await wait for the image to load or fail loading
      await waitForImage(image)
      console.log(`loading ${image.src} finished`)
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(`loading ${image.src} failed`)
    }
  }
}

loadImages();
```

Comment: This is a much more complete example than mine, where I just outlined the general method. As a small optimisation you can do if the conditions are right, note that checking `img.complete` is unnecessary if you set `img.src` after you set `img.onload` and `img.onerror`. (Of course, we can't see `img.src` being set in OP's short example, so the check is definitely warranted)

Comment: @Amadan I agree with that (personally I would still do that check because then I don't need to worry about the order and can move that in a utility function). In your example, you should add the `onerror` case. This can be a bit of a nightmare to debug if this is missing.

Comment: I tried adapting my function to resemble what you suggested but it gave an error requiring my function to be async in order for there to be an await at the new promise line

Comment: @YeoBryan then you are missing the `async` in front of the function in which your `for` loop is.